# Get app's data from Play Store, knowing app's ID

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I know that this question has beeing asked before… but somehow all the answers are incomplete, not applyable or (mostly) outdated.

So, I'm asking now, in 2018:

**Is there a way to access app's details, knowing its ID (e.g. com.companyName.appName), on the Play Store, the largest mobile Marketplace?**

Is there an official API?
Browsing the GoogleApis, I didn't find any.

Is there a way to obtain theese data in another way (e.g. some nuget package)?

Or do we still need to analyze the app's HTML web page, searching for the correct nodes?

I need to access this data using C#.

Best regards.

Comment: Still have to scrape the html, which, BTW, is a TOS issue.

Comment: @SushiHangover Really? Pity… P.S.: what does it mean "TOS"?

Comment: TOS = Terms of Service , Google does not legally permit 3rd-parties to scrape Google Play Store, unless you are a registered search engine with them (like Bing, Baidu, ...)

Comment: @SushiHangover , I understand, Thanks. I'll go for scraping then.

Comment: @LucaLindholm Not sure if you understood what Sushi just said: This is **illegal**. If you still intend to do this, at least don't state that you will on a public site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API for getting app info from playstore, the only way is to scrape the website which is not legal but a lot of websites are doing it so i guess google is cool about it